# Calling ffmpeg from command line does not wait until file was fully written do hard drive

Tags: java, command-line, ffmpeg

I am currently working on a service to allower conversion of audio files. I am using `ffmpeg` under the hood and use the `Runtime` in order to make the call.

After the call I read the converted file and upload it to a cloud storage.

**The problem:**

The problem is, that reading the file back from the drive gives me only a few bytes. After investigating, it actually has like 5 MB on the drive but `readFileToByArray()` reads only a few kb. I assume this is because the file was not completely persisted at the point where I want to read it back.

Is there any way I can make sure that `ffmpeg` is done writing to the hard drive? It seems that the main process that `ffmpeg` was running in finishes before a parallel process that is responsible for writing. Maybe?

Below is the relevant code that converts an arbitrary file to AAC-format:

```java
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("input-", ".tmp", new File("/tmp"));
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
outStream.write(bytes);

String convertedFilePath = String.format("/tmp/output-%s.aac", UUID.randomUUID().toString());

String command = String.format(
        "ffmpeg -i %s -c:a aac -b:a 256k %s",
        tempFile.getAbsolutePath(),
        convertedFilePath
);

LOGGER.debug(String.format("Converting file to AAC; Running %s", command));

Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec(command);
try {
    process.waitFor(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Time out");
}

File convertedFile = new File(convertedFilePath);
byte[] result = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(convertedFile);

// Upload "result" to cloud storage ..
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dim but, if you specifically allow `process.waitFor()` to time out, how can you be sure that the `ffmpeg` process has actually finished? Are you sure it doesn't take longer than that?

Comment: In fact, if you don't capture the standard output from `ffmpeg` in your code, can you be sure it's even _started_?

Comment: @KevinBoone I am capturing the output a but further down the lines. I check if `result.length` is greater than 0. If not I assume that an error happened. I have to allow a time-out or otherwise the thread gets stuck forever - which is not a good idea. I am sure it finished because the timeout was not reached.

Comment: I'm sure it started because the file gets written. I never encountered a situation where it didn't get started. The file gets written correctly as I said but I think this writing is done by a child process which hasn't finished at the time where I read that file back in.

Comment: Well, yes; I guess the question is whether the main `ffmpeg` process can complete, while some subsidiary process is still writing to disk. I've always assumed that isn't the case, but then I've been mostly running it at the prompt, and I don't type all that fast. I guess you could use `strace` or equivalent, to check whether something is being `fork`ed by `ffmpeg`. I'd still be concerned about calling `waitFor()` before starting a thread to consume `ffmpeg`'s `stdout`, though. This doesn't look very robust.

Comment: @KevinBoone Actually, I think I misunderstood how `waitFor` is working. I thought it is blocking and throws an exception on time out.. instead it returns `false`. So.. now I have increased the time out value to 30 seconds and check if `waitFor` returns `true` or `false`. This seems to work .. So you might be right after all, I probably should not give a time out value at all?

Comment: This behaviour is in line with the docs: "Returns:  true if the subprocess has exited and false if the waiting time elapsed before the subprocess has exited." An exception is only thrown if the process is terminated by another thread, I think. You probably only need a timeout to handle complete failures, where the process never exits, and I guess that can be long.

Comment: @KevinBoone Hm, yet I cannot just call `wait()` because that gets me: `IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner`. I guess I have to investigate further  to see what I should to.

Comment: @StefanFalk `wait()` is an entirely different method, and intended for waiting conditions when signalling between threads, and is not something you should call in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you don't wait enough for `ffmpeg` process to finish and after only 200 milliseconds you go on trying to read the converted file without checking whether `ffmpeg` process exited correctly.

from [`waitFor​(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) (emphasis mine):

> Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated, **or the specified waiting time elapses**.
>
> ...
>
> Returns:
>
> true if the process has exited and **false if the waiting time elapsed before the process has exited**.

here a rewrite of your code that takes advantage of `waitFor()` return value to decide if it needs to keep waiting or not:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.Runtime;
import java.lang.RuntimeException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class FFmpeg
{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
                /* just for testing purpose */
                File fooFile = new File("foo.mp3");
                byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(fooFile.toPath());

                File tempFile = File.createTempFile("input-", ".tmp", new File("/tmp"));
                OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                outStream.write(bytes);
                outStream.close();

                String convertedFilePath = String.format("output-%s.aac", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                String command = String.format(
                        "ffmpeg -nostdin -i %s -c:a aac -b:a 256k %s",
                        tempFile.getAbsolutePath(),
                        convertedFilePath
                );

                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process process = runtime.exec(command);

                System.out.print("converting");
                while ( ! process.waitFor(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                        /* here you have the opportunity to kill the process if
                         * it is taking too long, print something etc.. */
                        System.out.print(".");
                }
                System.out.print("\n");

                if (process.exitValue() != 0) {
                        System.err.printf("ffmpeg failed with value %d\n", process.exitValue());
                        return;
                }

                File convertedFile = new File(convertedFilePath);
                byte[] result = Files.readAllBytes(convertedFile.toPath());
                System.out.println(result.length);
        }
}
```

and a little demo:

```
$ ls -l
total 5368
-rw-r--r-- 1 marco marco    1557 Oct 10 17:46 FFmpeg.java
-rw-r--r-- 1 marco marco 5486341 Oct 10 17:09 foo.mp3
$ javac FFmpeg.java
$ java FFmpeg
converting.........
7329962
$ ls -l
total 12528
-rw-r--r-- 1 marco marco    1793 Oct 10 17:49 FFmpeg.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 marco marco    1557 Oct 10 17:46 FFmpeg.java
-rw-r--r-- 1 marco marco 5486341 Oct 10 17:09 foo.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 marco marco 7329962 Oct 10 17:50 output-176a2e73-82d6-483b-8a40-aec0819c749f.aac
$
```

(length of converted file is printed at the end, notice how it matches the one in `ls` output).

another important thing I added is the `-nostdin` flag to `ffmpeg` command. `ffmpeg` is often run as an interactive program taking user input from `stdin` e.g. when it asks if you want to overwrite target file. here of course we don't have the chance to answer "yes" or "no" and `-nostdin` will make the process to fail and exit when a user interaction is required. without that flag, it will wait for user input indefinitely (you maybe interested in `-y` and `-n` flags also).